# Trying to compile GTK+3 without GLX

Tags: opengl-es, gtk3, glx

I am trying to use GTK+3 on an embedded system that has OpenGLES, and there is no GLX on that platform.

My test program is as simple as :

```
main()
{
   gtk_init();
}
```

As soon as I start this test program, I have a runtime error : glXQueryExtension() not found in libGLESv2.so

So something is calling glxQueryExtension.... And I don't know if it is Cairo or Gtk or X11...

Assuming it is GTK+3, do you know if GTK+3 can be built without GLX ?

Thanks for any suggestion !